# Multiple page registration in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to create a registration page that is split across multiple pages.
-First page the user enters basic info (password, email etc)
-Second page, with more information stored in the User database field
-Third, stores information in a model from another table.

I would like the user to be saved only at the end of the process. Should I use the session to store the data? I could use the wizard component but I'm not sure if its the right way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all the three registration pages in a single ctp file and just show hide the respective portion of the page, once the user is done with filling all the three pages submit the form and save the data in their respective tables but you need to be careful about model field validations.

Comment: This was my first thought but how to I handle validation errors gracefully? Thanks for your suggestion by the way

Comment: Yes you can implement ajax validations for each step so that in the end when you finally submit the form, your page will have no error.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX forms for this , this way you can check any levels of pages without refreshing the parent page

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps splitting your registration form into chunks and putting them in [jQuery UI tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)?
This way, technically it's just one page, but visually it's split into seperate pieces.

I use jQuery UI tabs for some large forms in my own Cake apps aswell, works like a charm. All the data is read/saved in one request and you don't have to hassle with sessions.